# Android - Get HTTP Post Response in other activity

Tags: java, android, post, response

I created two activities one contains some text fields which accepts data. From other activity(Async Task) this data is sent to the server and gets the response from the server.

I am able to log the response but unable to store that response in variable and user in other activities. Is there any way to do that?

Here is one activity,

RegisterDevice.java

```
package sys.darpan.tracking;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class RegisterDevice extends Activity{

EditText regEmail, regPassword, regImei, regDeviceName, regVehicleNumber;
Button regButton;
AsyncRegisterDevice asd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register_device);

    regEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.regEmail);
    regPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.regPassword);
    regVehicleNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.regVehicleNum);
    regImei = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.regImei);
    regDeviceName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.regDeviceName);
    regButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.regButton);

    regImei.setText("165465416416416");
    regDeviceName.setText("GT-I9300");

    regButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            registerDevice();               
        }
    });
}

protected void registerDevice(){

    asd = new AsyncRegisterDevice();

    String email = regEmail.getText().toString();
    String password = regPassword.getText().toString();
    String imei = regImei.getText().toString();
    String deviceName = regDeviceName.getText().toString();
    String vehicleNo = regVehicleNumber.getText().toString();

    String aobj[] = new String[5];
    aobj[0] = email;
    aobj[1] = password;
    aobj[2] = vehicleNo;
    aobj[3] = imei;
    aobj[4] = deviceName;
    asd.execute(aobj);
}
}
```

Here is Async Task,

```
package sys.darpan.tracking;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class AsyncRegisterDevice extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
String sb;
String finalResult;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    String email = params[0];
    String password = params[1];
    String vnumber = params[2];
    String imei = params[3];
    String deviceName = params[4];

    DefaultHttpClient defaulthttpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://logicvibes.com/vts/register-device.php");

    ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> arraylist = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>(5);
    arraylist.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    arraylist.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", password));
    arraylist.add(new BasicNameValuePair("vno", vnumber));
    arraylist.add(new BasicNameValuePair("imei", imei));
    arraylist.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dname", deviceName));
    try
    {
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(arraylist));
        httppost.getAllHeaders();
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException unsupportedencodingexception)
    {
        unsupportedencodingexception.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
            // HttpResponse is an interface just like HttpPost.
            //Therefore we can't initialize them
            HttpResponse httpResponse = defaulthttpclient.execute(httppost);

            // According to the JAVA API, InputStream constructor do nothing. 
            //So we can't initialize InputStream although it is not an interface
            InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            String bufferedStrChunk = null;

            while((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
            }
            sb = stringBuilder.toString();
            Log.d("Custom resp: ", sb);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return null;
}

@Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String sb) {
       Log.d("RESULT", "Result : " + sb);//this returns NULL
       finalResult = sb;

 }

public String getFinalResult() {
    return finalResult;
}
}
```

I searched a lot but no luck, please tell me the proper way to do this.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722978/how-to-return-data-from-asynctask-to-main-thread

Comment: I don't want to use json

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13815807/return-value-from-asynctask-class-onpostexecute-method

Comment: Yes actually the first one solves the issue, thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using,

```
try {
        asd.execute(aobj).get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The main thread waits until the async task finished processing. (good for short processes)